# Enable Hotspot without an internet connection

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-11, hotspot

I'm a developer and I often need to connect to embedded devices without having an internet connection (for instance, a Raspberry Pi).

However, Windows would not let me create a hotspot network unless I'm connected to the internet. Could someone advise how to proceed?

Windows 11 Pro, on a Thinkpad E14 Gen 4

---

Some solutions I considered:

- I could simply create a hotspot from my Pi but I also often want to connect to it while my laptop is connected to a different Wi-Fi network, so this can't work.
- Many people have asked a similar question in the past and have been directed to use a Hosted Network. I get `Hosted network supported: No` from my Command Prompt, so I cannot use this.

Comment: You can put your Raspberry PI on your Wireless network. I do this. Works fine.

Comment: @John I'm in a college and that has a limit of one device per student so I cannot connect my laptop and Pi together (and personal routers/WAPs are banned). That's the reason this question came about — I do use my Wi-Fi router at home for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TabbySL/Enable-Windows-Hotspot-When-theres-No-Internet

I uploaded some (.reg) files in my GitHub page.

When you click the 'enable.reg' file, it enables hotspot even when theres no internet connection.
When you click the 'disable.reg' file, it disables the hotspot.  Its easy!

hope this helps!